# Java logic for clients and bank offers

Tags: java

I want to programme simple skeleton of clients and offers. Can ya check if this logic has sense?

.

ADRESS with postalCode pattern.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public abstract class Adress {

    private String postalCode;
    private String pattern = "[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    private void setPostalCode(String pc) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(pc);
        if (m.find()) {
            postalCode = m.group();
        } else {
            postalCode = "-----";
        }
    }

    public Adress() {

    }

    public Adress(String pc) {
        setPostalCode(pc);
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

}
```

CONTACT ADRESS - where to send letters.

```
public class AdressContact extends Adress {

    public AdressContact() {

    }

    public AdressContact(String pc) {
        super(pc);
    }
}
```

REGISTRATION ADRESS - where the company or person is registered.

```
public class AdressRegistered extends Adress {

    public AdressRegistered() {

    }

    public AdressRegistered(String pc) {
        super(pc);
    }
}
```

PERSON with registered adress and nip.
    public class Person {

```
    int nip;
    AdressRegistered adressRegistered;

}
```

CLIENT with adresses (postal codes).

```
public class Client extends Person {

    Adress adressContact;
    Adress adressRegistered;

    public Client(int nip) {
        this.nip = nip;
    }

    public Client(int nip, String ar) {
        this.nip = nip;
        adressRegistered = new AdressRegistered(ar);
    }

    public Client(int nip, String ar, String ac) {
        this.nip = nip;
        adressRegistered = new AdressRegistered(ar);
        adressContact = new AdressContact(ac);
    }

    public int getNip() {
        return nip;
    }

    public String getPostalCodeRegistered() {
        return adressRegistered.getPostalCode();
    }

    public String getPostalCodeContact() {
        return adressContact.getPostalCode();
    }
}
```

BANK AGENCY with adress

```
public class Agency {

    Adress adress;

    public Agency(String postalCode) {
        adress = new AdressContact(postalCode);

    }

}
```

THE LOAN OFFER

```
public class Offer {
    Client client;

/* and more characteristics here */

    Offer(Client c) {
        this.client = c;
    }

}
```

Comment: _"Can ya check if this logic has sense?"_ which _logic_ in particular?

Comment: Please tell us more about what you intend to achieve using this code — see [ask].

Comment: By logic i mean the structure, the connections of classes. By this code I want achieve nothing. Just this is a structure for something more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Adress` contains absolutely no abstract methods. There is no reason for it to be abstract.

There is also no reason for the classes `AdressContact` and `AdressRegistered` to be separate classes from `Adress`. There is no reason to extend the class at all.

Remove the classes `AdressContact` and `AdressRegistered` and skip the `abstract` part of `Adress`.

And by the way, the correct English spelling is `Address`.

Comment: Thank you! That was whaa I was lookin for. And if the class Address has more variables like "street, city, country" then it is sense to keep Address as separate class?

Comment: @wBacz `Address` should always be a class. An address is an address no matter what fields it has. I see no need at the moment to have separate classes for it.

Comment: Thank you, and what about `postalCode`? Maybe I should create a class `PostalCode` because it has special pattern?

Comment: @wBacz That could at times be useful, yes. But unless you have extensive validation for it, I'd say that keeping it as a `String` is good enough.